# (SQL) Syntax for SELECT GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, select

i need your help to find the correct syntax for my SQL request.

My database look like :

```
|id|col1|col2|
|1 |10  |A   |
|2 |10  |A   |
|3 |10  |B   |
|4 |99  |B   |
|5 |99  |B   |
```

result must be :

```
|col1|col2|
|10  |A   |
|10  |B   |
|99  |B   |
```

what is the correct syntax to find that result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`distinct` would do what you want:

```
select distinct col1, col2 from mytable
```